# in arrange displays two different external monitors of the same model are shown as one

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I have a Macbook pro, MacOs, which is connected to 2 external monitors.

the two monitors are of the same model, and are seen as one screen on the 'arrange displays' option:

### [image]

[image]

The thing is that these two monitors are both extending the inbuilt monitor, but they themselves are identical (show same image).

Any ideas as for how to fix this issue?

Regards!

Comment: how are they connected?

Comment: through a dock station. i have already got to connect with same dock 2 different external monitors and it worked perfectly.